# populate select element from state in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, select, drop-down-menu

New react developer here, trying to learn by coding, here I am stuck with simple select element, I have select element and inside it using map to populate options, i'm also consoling logging my data inside map and getting '50 getting data FUNDING_ACCOUNT'.

what I want to achieve is: a select element which user clicks and gets 'data.name' as dropdown, where is my mistake?

English is not my mother language so there could be mistakes.

i'm using fetch to populate 'setUpdateSelect'

My code:

```js
  const [updateSelect, setUpdateSelect] = useState([]);


<select>
          {updateSelect.map((data) => {
            console.log("getting data", data.name);
            <option key={data.name} value={data.name}>
              {data.name}
            </option>;
          })}
        </select>
```

Comment: what is the issue ?? can you explain more detail

Comment: at the moment when i click select element i am getting nothing...

Answer (score 1):

With a map function, it should **return** something. In your map function it doesn't return anything.

#### Modified code

```js
{updateSelect.map((data) => {
   console.log("getting data", data.name);
    return (
      <option key={data.name} value={data.name}>
        {data.name}
      </option>
    );
})}
```

This should now work properly.

Thanks,

Arjis Chakraborty.

Comment: oh that was simple mistake, now its working

Comment: Glad to know it started working. Could you please accept this answer so that others might also benefit from it?

Answer (score 0):

```
const [updateSelect, setUpdateSelect] = useState([]);

<select>
    {updateSelect.map((data) => {
        return( console.log("getting data", data.name);
                <option key={data.name} value={data.name}>
                  {data.name}
                </option>;)
               
     })}
</select>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For rerendering, you can use like this;

```
const [updateSelect, setUpdateSelect] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);


useEffect(() => {
 setLoading(true);
 setUpdateSelect(yourdata);
 setLoading(false);

},[yourdata])


return !loading ? (
<select>
 updateSelect.map((data, index) => (
  <option key={index} value={data.name}> 
   {data.name}
  </option>
 )
</select>
) : null;
```